# Nginx fresh codeigniter installation showing 404 Not Found when try to access controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I am using [nginx open source stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/nginx) from [bitnami.](https://bitnami.com/)

when i open `http://localhost/ci` it will display **codeigniter welcome page**, but when i try to access controller `http://localhost/ci/index.php/welcome` or `http://localhost/ci/welcome` it display *404 Not Found*

*nginx-app.conf*

```
 index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/opt/nginx/php/var/run/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

*nginx-prefix.conf*

```
location /ci {
    alias "/opt/nginx/apps/ci/htdocs";
    include "/opt/nginx/apps/ci/conf/nginx-app.conf";
}
```

*I am not using any virtual host.*

Comment: from where you download codeigniter????

Comment: from official site https://codeigniter.com/en/download